# Solving ode with the form of $\frac{dy}{dx} = y^2-1$ and some problems with region

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to solve ode of the form 
\begin{align}
\frac{dy}{dx} = y^2-1
\end{align}

Here is my solution

\begin{align}
&\int dx = \int \frac{1}{y^2-1} dy \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \int \left(\frac{1}{y-1} - \frac{1}{y+1} \right) dy = \frac{1}{2} \ln \left( \frac{|y-1|}{|y+1|} \right)
\end{align}

I want to discuss this solution for $|y|<1, |y|=1, |y|>1$. 
Can you give me some shape of this solution for each region?

---

Following Αδριανός and Jan Eerland, and via mathematica, i obtain

[image]

Now what i want to do is find the graph of x, y which Narasimham did.

Comment: @Moo, can you explain it more detail? Drawing a slope field how we can understand the shape of the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as you might imagine the graph of the solution has asymptotes at $y=-1,1$. Before -1, it just looks "like" the graph of $-\frac{1}{y}$, between the two numbers it is shaped like $-\tan(y)$, and then after $y=1$ it resumes looking like $y=-\frac{1}{y}$.

When $y=1$, it approaches to negative infinity.

That is what it is shaped like. Let me know if you need anything more rigorous.

Comment: what happen when $y=-1$? From your answer, i guess it approaches to positive infinity. Am i right?

Comment: Yes that's precisely right

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{\text{d}y(x)}{\text{d}x}=y(x)^2-1\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$y'(x)=y(x)^2-1\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{y'(x)}{y(x)^2-1}=1\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\int\frac{y'(x)}{y(x)^2-1}\space\text{d}x=\int1\space\text{d}x\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{\ln\left|1-y(x)\right|-\ln\left|1+y(x)\right|}{2}=x+\text{C}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\ln\left|1-y(x)\right|-\ln\left|1+y(x)\right|=2x+\text{C}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\ln\left|\frac{y(x)-1}{y(x)+1}\right|=2x+\text{C}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\left|\frac{y(x)-1}{y(x)+1}\right|=\exp\left[2x+\text{C}\right]\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\left|\frac{y(x)-1}{y(x)+1}\right|=\text{C}\exp\left[2x\right]\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{\left|y(x)-1\right|}{\left|y(x)+1\right|}=\text{C}\exp\left[2x\right]$$

Comment: Yes the C is important.

Answer (score 1):

It is a non-repeating  tanh(x)   related function, $ |y|<1 $, curve is asymptotic to $ y= \pm 1 $ and has a slope = $-1$ at the origin. It clarifies to express it in $tanh $ form.

[image]

Comment: How do you obtain the graph of this?

Comment: It is not a full graph but plotted in the region $|y|<1$  directly by Mathematica. It coincides with the graph you gave in region between asymptotes. Due to double values of inverse function in range for x as function of y Mathematica avoided the outside regions. I can indicate the curve outside the parallel asymptotes but I think you already know. Note there is no curve in 1,3 quadrants, when x,y are both >0 or both <0.