# solving ode with the form of $\frac{dy}{dx} = y^3-y$ and some problems with region

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

This is an extension version of my previous question [solving ode with the form of $\frac{dy}{dx} = y^2-1$ and some problems with region](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1724499/solving-ode-with-the-form-of-fracdydx-y2-1-and-some-problems-with-regi).

What if i modify the RHS as 
\begin{align}
\frac{dy}{dx} = y^3-y
\end{align}

The solution i found is 
\begin{align}
\int dx& = \int \frac{1}{y(y-1)(y+1)} dy = \int \left( - \frac{1}{y} + \frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{y+1} + \frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{y-1} \right)dy  \\
&
 = \ln \left( \frac{|y+1|^{\frac{1}{2}} |y-1|^{\frac{1}{2}}}{|y|} \right)
\end{align}

I want to find some brief sketch of solution in terms of regions for $y$, i.e, $y=-1, 0, 1$ and between and outside the region.

Is there any strategy to find this kinds of region problem?

Comment: @Moo, yes i have the program,  Mathematica, and actually i conduct the plot, but here the reason why i post a question is to understand the process of determining the shape not just want a shape of the form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than giving a similar answer as your prior question, let me give you a tool so that you can see the solution immediately.

Note that if you want to do this by hand, do as @Moo says and draw a slope field. You can also try to draw the function itself (all of these examples so far have been doable in 2 dimensions) by note that the $\ln$ merely "depresses" the graph, dragging it out. Whenever the function inside is zero, you will get an infinity.

But if you are allowed a computer/calculator, I strongly suggest giving [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator) a try. By graphing $\ln(f(x))$ versus $f(x)$ you can see the effect which the logarithm has on the graph and playing around with the graph, you can begin to notice patterns...

EDIT 1: 
Notice that when $y>>0$, then all of the terms are positive and this is equivalent to $\ln(\frac{\sqrt{y+1}\sqrt{y-1}}{y})=\ln(\frac{\sqrt{y^2-1}}{y})$.

That is, you will find the equation describing the graph for $y≥1$. Now, continue on, taking cases. Notice that when you are between -1 and 1, the first absolute value signs kick in, and for very small $y<<0$, it behaves big $y$-values, except it is flipped.